# Unity 3d Photon network how to split the screen both player see just view of each other?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I need little help I make tricky tower game for PC I use photon Pun for multiplayer I need just share view to both side where 1st player watch 2nd player game and second one also see the view first player but when I do implement its not work properly when I create room i see only my game scene view and other when i join i see own view so both are in different view so what i do ?
i see many YouTube tutorial but its not work[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 Cameras and setup their Viewport Rect setting to have them horizontally paralel on screen.

[image: Like that]

Comment: thanks for the response my problem still when I join the room i am not see the other player update i only have scene with two split